# Unable to connect to my Docker RabbitMQ using Node.js

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq

I have installed a RabbitMQ docker image and have it up and running.
My docker management console is also running on port 8080.

I run the docker with `docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3`

I am trying to run the following node code;

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

var connection = amqp.connect('amqp://localhost:5672',function(err,conn){
    console.log(conn); });
```

However, conn is always undefined.

I have tried;

```
amqp://localhost:5672
amqp://localhost:15672
amqp://localhost
amqp://localhost:8080
```

but none of them work.

My rabbitmq manager says amqp is listening on 5672.

I have not got any other accounts other than the default guest account.

I'm not running visual studio code in admin mode.

The error I am getting is;

> Error: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake
>       at Socket.endWhileOpening (C:\Users\sgrieger\Documents\Development\rabbitmq\node_modules\amqplib\lib\connection.js:259:17)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Comment: Do you have a docker file?  What image are you using? How do you start the docker image?

Comment: @RobertMoskal, yes I have a docker file else I wouldn't be running it.  I got the image this morning so it's the latest 3.7.7.

docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3

Comment: RabbitMQ is listening to port 5672 _inside_ the container. You have to port map from the host's port to the container's.

`docker run -d -p 5672:5672 --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3`

Comment: @Rickkwa.  Fantastic!  Thank you.  If you'd like to write that in the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't exposing the ports on the host when you run the docker image. You can do that with the `-p` switch:

```
 docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit -p 5672:5672 --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3
```

Comment: Did you down vote this?  No problem if you did, i'd just like to know why if so.

Comment: Because it was incomplete. Put in the run command and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Done.  Sorry I missed that one.